# How to load a project that overlaps the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I open Eclipse, it asks for a workspace. I provide one, say c:\foo. The workspace folder already has Eclipse projects in it. When Eclipse loads **there are no projects in the Project Explorer Window**. So, I select File/Import/General/Existing Projects into Workspace. I enter c:\foo as my root directory. I select a project in c:\foo and I get this:

"c:\foo overlaps the workspace location c:\foo"

What is the correct way to get the project into the Project Explorer?

This is not a duplicate because similar questions were never answered except to provide workarounds

Comment: The workaround is the solution because you can't have overlapping workspaces

Comment: You could delete the `.project` file in those folders, then you should be able to re-import them (after you select the parent directory of the projects you want to import)

Comment: @cricket_007  I don't want to have overlapping workspaces. I want to import a project into a workspace.

Comment: Well, `c:\foo` is the workspace, so you cannot select that same folder to import folders already there because those would conflict with the existing projects in that workspace folder.